# Salt dockerng.image_present returns missing Docker credentials

Tags: saltstack

Am trying create a state file `sls` to make sure latest image is available before launching docker container using salt.

my salt-minion version is 2015.8.1 and my docker-py version 1.5

```
prep sentry images:
  dockerng.image_present:
    - force: true
    - name:
        - redis:latest
```

Although the above block returns the following error

```
 Comment: Encountered error pulling prep sentry images:latest: Missing Docker credentials. Please see the dockerng remote execution module documentation for information on how to configure authentication.
```

When I try to login to client via ssh and pull the image with `docker pull redis` it works fine and docker doesn't ask for credentials

When docker is pulled the script does not fail though,

can someone advise please?

Comment: Perhaps related issue: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/28004

Answer (score 1):

You must specify credentials in your config

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.dockerng.html#authentication

Comment: This was an issue before, fixed now in 2015.8.8.

Answer (score 0):

Your sls file does not look correct. Try this one:

```
prep sentry images:
  dockerng.image_present:
    - force: true
    - name: redis:latest
```

In your example docker is trying to pull 'prep sentry images'.

Comment: even with this format am getting same error :/

Comment: Did you try: prep_sentry_images without spaces?